# Value in <p:inputText> won't pass to bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem with my code where the values from various `'s won't pass over to the bean. The code is basically the same as my old projects (where everything worked perfectly fine), but no matter what I do the values in the bean won't be updated. What I want to do is for the user to fill in a form in order to register an account. I tried doing it in two ways:

```
<p:inputText id="address" value="#{Register.user.address}.../>
```

Here `Register` is the bean with the property user of the User class, where there are several properties including `String` address. This didn't really work, so I tried putting the getters and setters in the RegisterBean, and setting them to this format

```
public String getAddress(){
    return user.getAdress();
}
```

and using them like this in the xhtml

```
<p:inputText id="address" value="#{Register.address]".../>
```

but it still doesn't work. Tried debugging, and it appears that the setters are never entered at all. Does anybody know why this doesn't work and potentially how to fix it?

Here is the rest of the code:

The .xhtml

```
<h:head>
        <title>Register</title>
    </h:head>
    <body>
        <ui:composition template="userTemplate.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form>
                    <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="3" >
                        <f:facet name="header">
                             Please fill in the required information  
                        </f:facet> 
                    <p:outputLabel value="Username" />
                    <p:inputText  id="username" value="#{Register.user.username}" validator="#{Register.validateUsername}" required="true" requiredMessage="Cannot be blank!"/>
                    <p:message for="username"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Password"/>
                    <p:password id="password" value="#{Register.user.password}" validator="#{Register.validatePasswords}"/>
                    <p:message for="password" showSummary="true" showDetail="false"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Repeat password" />
                    <p:password id="repPassword" value="#{Register.user.repeatPass}" validator="#{Register.validateRepPassword}"/>
                    <p:message for="repPassword" showSummary="true" showDetail="false"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="First name" />
                    <p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{Register.user.firstName}"/> 
                    <p:message for="firstName" showSummary="true" showDetail="false"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Surname" />
                    <p:inputText id="surname" value="#{Register.user.surname}" required="true" requiredMessage="Cannot be blank!"/> 
                    <p:message for="surname" showSummary="true" showDetail="false"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Address" />
                    <p:inputText id="address"  value="#{Register.user.address}" required="true" requiredMessage="Cannot be blank!"/>
                    <p:message for="address" showSummary="true" showDetail="false"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Postnumber"/>
                    <p:inputText id="postnumber" value="#{Register.user.postnumber}" validatorMessage="Can only be numbers!" required="true" requiredMessage="Cannot be blank!"/>
                    <p:message for="postnumber" showSummary="true" showDetail="false"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="City"/>
                    <p:inputText id="city" value="#{Register.user.city}" required="true" requiredMessage="Cannot be blank!"/>
                    <p:message for="city" showSummary="true" showDetail="false"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="E-mail" />
                    <p:inputText id="email" validator="#{Register.user.validateEmail}" value="#{Register.email}"/>
                    <p:message for="email" showSummary="true" showDetail="false"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Phone number" />
                    <p:inputText id="phone" value="#{Register.user.phone}" required="true" validatorMessage="Phone number must be between 8 and 16 numbers long" requiredMessage="Cannot be blank!">
                        <f:validateLongRange  minimum="8" maximum="16"/>
                    </p:inputText> 
                    <p:message for="phone" showDetail="false" showSummary="true"/>
                    <p:commandButton type="submit" id="submitButton" value="submit" update="grid" ajax="true"/>
                    <p/>
                    #{Register.user}
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

The bean:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="Register")
public class registerBean implements Serializable {
private User user = new User();

public void validateUsername(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    String message = "";
    String username = (String) value;
    if(username == null || username.equals("")) {
        ((UIInput)component).setValid(false);
        message = "Enter a username";
        context.addMessage(component.getClientId(context), new FacesMessage(message));
    }
    //else user.setUsername(username);
}

public void validatePasswords(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    String message = "";
    String password = (String) value;
    boolean hasNumber = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i))) {
            hasNumber = true;
        }
    }
    if(!hasNumber && password.length() < 8) {
        ((UIInput)component).setValid(false);
        message = "You need to have at least one number and the password must be atleast 8 characters long";
        context.addMessage(component.getClientId(context), new FacesMessage(message));
    }
    //else user.setPassword(password);
}

public void validateRepPassword(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    String message = "";
    String repPassword = (String) value;
    if(!repPassword.equals(user.getPassword())) {
        ((UIInput)component).setValid(false);
        message = "The passwords don't match.";
        context.addMessage(component.getClientId(context), new FacesMessage(message));
    }
    //else user.setRepeatPass(repPassword);

}
public void validatePostnumber(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    String message = "";
    try {
      Integer postnumber = (Integer) value;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ((UIInput)component).setValid(false);
        message = "The postnumber can only be numbers";
        context.addMessage(component.getClientId(context), new FacesMessage(message));
    }
    //user.setPostnumber(((Integer) value).intValue());
}
public void validateEmail(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    String message = "";
    try {
        InternetAddress email = new InternetAddress((String) value);
        email.validate();
    } catch(AddressException ae) {
        ((UIInput)component).setValid(false);
        message = "Type a valid email address";
        context.addMessage(component.getClientId(context), new FacesMessage(message));
    }
    //user.setEmail((String)value);
}
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
}
```

And finally the normal User java class

```
public class User {

private String username;
private String password;
private String repeatPass;
private String address;
private int postnumber;
private String city;
private String firstName;
private String surname;
private String email;
private long phone;

+setters/getters and a toString()
}
```

Comment: Try adding `process="@this"` to your commandButton.  Does this work?  If not then you probably have a validation error on the form submission and the values are not getting applied to the model.  To verify this see if `immediate="true"` on the commandButton invokes the managed bean setter methods.

Comment: did you try using an actionListener method with the button?

Comment: Check your browser's javascript console (on the network tab) to observe any silent validation/conversion errors

Comment: Thanks for answers, but nothing has worked so far... I tried removing the validators from the inputText's and then everything worked. Has to be a way for me to use validators this way as well though, right?

Comment: Your validators are completely wrongly designed. Get rid of them all and use e.g. `required="true" requiredMessage="Enter an username"` for username and `<f:validateRegex>` for password. This however doesn't explain why the form isn't processed in first place. A real SSCCE would help. The code provided so far is not copy'n'paste'n'runnable and contains too much irrelevant noise.

Comment: Try setting ajax="false" on the command button, temporary. This might give you some more detailed information about what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I feel kinda stupid, but there wasn't really any problem from the start. The thing was that because of all the validators and everything, the validation was set to false on several fields which led to the fact that the values didn't pass back. As soon as I set all correct information, it worked.